# Exclude remotes in git log --all?

Tags: git

I want to inspect all commits in the main namespace (i.e. refs/heads/*) via git log, that is, to exclude refs/remotes, refs/original, etc. Is there a simple command to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for Sunlis' hint, I found that this works:

```
git log --branches=*
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
git log --all --not --remotes=*
```

Comment: It simply shows nothing. However I found that another way works. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Good for you, @DannyLin. Can you tell us what that other way is?

Comment: @Felizett See my self answer.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me on `git` version 2.39.0:

```bash
git log --decorate-refs-exclude=refs/remotes --all
```